Smaller module ranks of MLWE imply more algebraic structure?
In CRYSTALS-Kyber, they mentioned that the module rank $k$ should not be too small, they argued "having a smaller $k$ implies more algebraic structure, making the scheme potentially susceptible to more avenues of attack". I'm confused with what this structure refers to.
Perhaps I myself can understand two things about the role of module rank in security:

Larger module means bigger scale of computation (more randomness to guess in one sample)
Larger module means more secure sublattices, as they say, "larger module dimension also decreases the relative dimension of the dense sub-lattice", so larger module helps avoiding attacks on low-dim sub-lattice.

So maybe one aspect of this "structure" means the dimension of sub-lattices? thus implying Ring-LWE/NTRU(kind of $k=1$) is prone to be attacked from the sub-lattices?
And is there any other reasons? How should we see the role of module rank in security of MLWE and MLWR? I would appreciate any intuitions or materials, Thanks a lot!

Module lattice is actually a mathematical term (I only recently discovered). So "having smaller k" probably means having an underlying ring of larger rank, which corresponds to more structure.

"k=1" corresponds to "ideal lattices", i.e., RLWE (no need for "kind of"). If you want to know the high-level pro and contra using structured or unstructured lattices, you could listen to Vadim Lyubashevsky's invited talk to EuroCrypto 2023 starting around 9min15s into the video (it's worth listening completely).

Thanks @garfunkel, I listened to the talk and that's a wonderful story about lattices and academia of cryptology.

Dan Bernstein has an email to the NIST PQC mailing list going over this argument. He does not find the argument convincing, but he does make what "less structured" means relatively precise. I'll copy a particular quantitative section of it below.

Let's compare three choices [of algebraic structure].
I'll describe each choice as a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra, which means a ring $R$ (not necessarily commutative) equipped with a ring morphism from $\mathbb{Q}\to R$. Here $\mathbb{Q}$ is the field of rational numbers.
I'll abbreviate $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra as simply "algebra".
Each of these algebras acts as a set of linear transformations on the module $\mathbb{Q}^{1024}$.
I'll skip reviewing the standard mechanisms to extract important "integral" subrings (e.g., extracting $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^{1024}+1)$ from $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^{1024}+1)$) and to reduce modulo $q$, giving linear transformations on $\mathbb{Z}^{1024}$ and on $(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^{1024}$.
Here are the three choices of algebras:

"The LWE choice": $\mathbb{Q}^{1024\times 1024}$, the algebra of $1024\times 1024$ matrices over $\mathbb{Q}$, with each matrix viewed as a linear transformation on the module $\mathbb{Q}^{1024}$ in the usual way. There are $1024\times 1024 = \mathbf{1048576}$ degrees of freedom in a matrix.

"The MLWE choice": $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^{256}+1)^{4\times 4}$, the algebra of $4\times 4$ matrices with entries in the ring $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^{256}+1)$. Each of these matrices is viewed as a $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^{256}+1)$-linear transformation, and hence $\mathbb{Q}$-linear transformation, on the module $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^{256}+1)^4$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^{1024}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-module.
There are only $256\times 4 \times 4 = \mathbf{4096}$ degrees of freedom here. This is a small, highly structured subalgebra of the first algebra.

"The RLWE choice": $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^{1024}+1)$, with each element viewed as the linear transformation that multiplies by that element.
There are only $\mathbf{1024}$ degrees of freedom here. This is an even smaller, even more highly structured subalgebra.


It's easy to prove that the third algebra is a subalgebra of the second, and that solving various problems for transformations of the second type implies solving various problems for transformations of the third type.

As mentioned, Dan's post is against this type of argument that chooses MLWE > RLWE as it is "less structured", though I'd direct readers who are interested in the details of Dan's argument to just click the link and read it themself.
